# R: passing a value over multiple rows, until a value in a different column changes

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I've got the customer activity data in the following format:

```
id = rep(1:2, each = 7)
week = rep(22:28, 2)
orders_num = c(NA, 1,0,0,0,3,0,1,4,0,0,1,0,0)
orders_char = c("none", "1", "none", "none", "none", "2+", "none", "1", "2+", "none", "none","1", "none", "none")
activity =c(NA, "active", "lapsed1", "lapsed2", "lapsed3", "active", "lapsed1", "active", "active", "lapsed1", "lapsed2" , "active", "lapsed1", "lapsed2")

df = data.frame(cbind(id, week, orders_num, orders_char, activity))
df
id week orders_num orders_char activity
 1   22       <NA>        none     <NA>
 1   23          1           1   active
 1   24          0        none  lapsed1
 1   25          0        none  lapsed2
 1   26          0        none  lapsed3
 1   27          3          2+   active
 1   28          0        none  lapsed1
 2   22          1           1   active
 2   23          4          2+   active
 2   24          0        none  lapsed1
 2   25          0        none  lapsed2
 2   26          1           1   active
 2   27          0        none  lapsed1
 2   28          0        none  lapsed2
```

I'm trying to create a column that would return a combination of `activity` and `orders_char` if `activity == "active"` and a respective `'lapsed'` category with `orders_char` corresponding to the most recent `'active'` status:

```
df_solution
id week orders_num orders_char activity      final
 1   22       <NA>        none     <NA>       <NA>
 1   23          1           1   active   active_1
 1   24          0        none  lapsed1  lapsed1_1
 1   25          0        none  lapsed2  lapsed2_1
 1   26          0        none  lapsed3  lapsed3_1
 1   27          3          2+   active  active_2+
 1   28          0        none  lapsed1 lapsed1_2+
 2   22          1           1   active   active_1
 2   23          4          2+   active  active_2+
 2   24          0        none  lapsed1 lapsed1_2+
 2   25          0        none  lapsed2 lapsed2_2+
 2   26          1           1   active   active_1
 2   27          0        none  lapsed1  lapsed1_1
 2   28          0        none  lapsed2  lapsed2_1
```

Obviously, simply referring to the previous row is not going to work in cases where `lapsed` periods last longer:

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% arrange(id, week) %>%
mutate(final = ifelse(activity == "active", paste(activity, orders_char, sep="_"),
                    ifelse(grepl("lapsed", activity), paste(activity, lag(orders_char), sep="_"), NA))) 

 id   week orders_num orders_char activity        final
  1     22         NA        none       NA         <NA>
  1     23          1           1   active     active_1
  1     24          0        none  lapsed1    lapsed1_1
  1     25          0        none  lapsed2 lapsed2_none
  1     26          0        none  lapsed3 lapsed3_none
  1     27          3          2+   active    active_2+
  1     28          0        none  lapsed1   lapsed1_2+
  2     22          1           1   active     active_1
  2     23          4          2+   active    active_2+
  2     24          0        none  lapsed1   lapsed1_2+
  2     25          0        none  lapsed2 lapsed2_none
  2     26          1           1   active     active_1
  2     27          0        none  lapsed1    lapsed1_1
  2     28          0        none  lapsed2 lapsed2_none
```

Is there any way I could "fix" `orders_char` value from one active period to the other?

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After grouping by 'id', and `arrange`ing by 'id' and 'week', we get the cumulative sum of logical vector (`orders_char!= 'none'`), replace that with the elements of 'orders_char' without the 'none' (`orders_char[orders_char != "none"]`) and `paste` with the 'activity' column.

```
df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   arrange(id, week) %>% 
   mutate(ind = cumsum(orders_char != "none"), 
          ind1 = ind*(NA^!ind), 
          final = ifelse(is.na(ind1), NA, paste(activity, 
                as.character(orders_char[orders_char!="none"])[ind1], sep="_"))) %>%
   select(-ind, -ind1) 

#      id   week orders_num orders_char activity      final
#   <fctr> <fctr>     <fctr>      <fctr>   <fctr>      <chr>
#1       1     22         NA        none       NA       <NA>
#2       1     23          1           1   active   active_1
#3       1     24          0        none  lapsed1  lapsed1_1
#4       1     25          0        none  lapsed2  lapsed2_1
#5       1     26          0        none  lapsed3  lapsed3_1
#6       1     27          3          2+   active  active_2+
#7       1     28          0        none  lapsed1 lapsed1_2+
#8       2     22          1           1   active   active_1
#9       2     23          4          2+   active  active_2+
#10      2     24          0        none  lapsed1 lapsed1_2+
#11      2     25          0        none  lapsed2 lapsed2_2+
#12      2     26          1           1   active   active_1
#13      2     27          0        none  lapsed1  lapsed1_1
#14      2     28          0        none  lapsed2  lapsed2_1
```

Comment: argh, I think I was too hasty accepting the answer, as after a closer inspection I see the code does not always return correct values, e.g. in the 5th row `final` column should return `lapsed3_1`, in the 7th should return `lapsed1_2+', etc. Basically, all `lapsed` cells should have `orders_char` value of the `active` status they follow, if that makes sense. Any suggestions how to achieve this? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @KasiaKulma  Can you please check now.  I think the `factor` class created some problems.

Comment: Fantastic, this one works like a charm, thanks a lot!